# List all the html tags in a file

Tags: shell, sed, scripting, grep

I want to know if there is a way to list all the html tags in a file. 
Lets say I have a file `file.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
This is a test
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to get a list of all the tags. That is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using sed,

```
cat file.html | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

But it removed all the html tags insted . . . .

Comment: [WHY GOD, WHY?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/792066)

Comment: I have read that before. . . But there has to be a way v.v

Comment: Which shell? bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick hack with perl:

```
perl -wlne 'print for(/<.*?>/g)' file.html
```

But for a serious solution you should use a tool that really understands html/xml.

Comment: I need a bash solution only :( sorry about that:/

Comment: Be aware that your `sed` solution is not bash only...

Comment: umm didnt know that :/ But your solution is so perfect :/

Comment: `grep -oP '<.*?>' filename`

Comment: @Cyrus also not bash-only...

Comment: @Unknown you almost certainly don't need a "bash only" solution. This will run on just about any *nix (except those very few that don't install `perl` by default). `sed` is not part of bash and neither is `cat`. What do you mean by "bash only"?

Comment: @terdon I didn't know that. I thought you have to externally install perl. : /.

Answer (score 2):

Using an actual html parser isn't that hard:

```
perl -MHTML::Parser -E '
  $handler = sub {say "<".shift.">"};
  HTML::Parser->new(start_h => [$handler,"tag"], end_h => [$handler,"tag"])
              ->parse_file(shift @ARGV)
' file.html
```

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```